# Sympy: How to simplify expression containing exp(I*x)

Tags: sympy, simplify

I want to achieve this kind of simplification:
`sqrt(2)*sqrt(pi)*(p**2 + (-p**2 + 4*pi**2)*exp(2*I*p) - 4*pi**2)*exp(-I*p)/(p**2 - 4*pi**2)**2=-2*I*sqrt(2*pi)*sin(p)/(p**2 - 4*pi**2)`

However, sympy.simplify can't simplify this expression:

```
f=sqrt(2)*sqrt(pi)*(p**2 + (-p**2 + 4*pi**2)*exp(2*I*p) -\
 4*pi**2)*exp(-I*p)/(p**2 - 4*pi**2)**2
print(sympy.simplify(f))
#sqrt(2)*sqrt(pi)*(p**2 + (-p**2 + 4*pi**2)*exp(2*I*p) - 4*pi**2)*exp(-I*p)/(p**2 - 4*pi**2)**2
```

How to simplify this expression with SymPy?

Besides, I don't want to use `Piecewise((sqrt(2)*I/(2*sqrt(pi)), Eq(p, -2*pi))...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just massage the expression a bit. You know that with fractions, you generally factorize them and then you cancel like-terms. Then you simplify after that:

```py
from sympy import *

p = Symbol("p", real=True)
f = sqrt(2)*sqrt(pi)*(p**2 + (-p**2 + 4*pi**2)*exp(2*I*p) - 4*pi**2)*exp(-I*p)/(p**2 - 4*pi**2)**2
f = simplify(expand(cancel(factor(f))))
print(f)
```

Gives

```
-2*sqrt(2)*I*sqrt(pi)*sin(p)/(p**2 - 4*pi**2)
```